# Obfuscating jar file using proguard

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I used `proguard` to obfuscate my jar file.
During processing I got the following errors:

```
Initializing...
Warning: tdvep.jmNb: can't find referenced class QSYGWO
Warning: tdvep.qmfsfjttKdvEpNz: can't find referenced class FVTYBN
Warning: tdvep.qsfboBcSw$qsffmtssf: can't find referenced class UGKTLU
Warning: tdvep.qsffmtssf: can't find referenced class DREQUQ
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
```

Please correct the above warnings first.
So guide me to resolve this warnings.

Comment: Go back to square one and rebuild all jars from code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the ProGuard troubleshooting section - [Problems while processing](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html).

If there are `unresolved references to classes or interfaces`, you most likely **forgot to specify an essential library**. For proper processing, all libraries that are referenced by your code must be specified, including the Java run-time library. For specifying libraries, use the `-libraryjars` option.

For example, if `ProGuard` complains that it can't find a `javax.crypto` class, you probably still have to specify `jce.jar, next to the more common rt.jar.`

If you're missing a library and you're absolutely sure it isn't used anyway, you can try your luck with the `-ignorewarnings` option, or even the `-dontwarn option`. Only use these options if you really know what you're doing though.

For example, if you're developing for `Android`, and ProGuard complains that it can't find a `java.awt class`, then some library that you are using is referring to `java.awt`. This is a bit shady, since Android doesn't have this package at all, but if your application works anyway, you can let `ProGuard` accept it with `"-dontwarn java.awt.**"`.

Comment: i got the following error                               Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [tdvep/jmNb]
  Method      = [<init>()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException] (-1)
-1

Comment: check this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/462099/open-source/While-processing-Proguard-getting-error).. i suggest you to look for help in the proguard help.. there may you get the solution with details and let you avoid these in future... hope this help..